# When should I store the original object or store a copy of it in a data structure?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, memory-management, reference

When creating a data structure in C / C ++ you have the freedom that the members of the structure can be the same objects or a copy of them. So my question is which of them is more recommended or in which case (s) should I use a certain method.

This code is in C, but the question itself can be translated into C++ as well. For example:
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct StackNode
{
    int *data;
    struct StackNode *prev;
} StackNode;

void Push1(StackNode **top, int *data)
{
    StackNode *newest = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    newest->data = data; // the same object

    if (*top) // if not empty
    {
        newest->prev = *top;
        *top = newest;
    }
    else
    {
        *top = newest;
        (*top)->prev = NULL;
    }
}

void Push2(StackNode **top, int *data)
{
    StackNode *newest = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    newest->data=malloc(sizeof(int));
    *newest->data = *data; // make a deep copy

    if (*top) // if not empty
    {
        newest->prev = *top;
        *top = newest;
    }
    else
    {
        *top = newest;
        (*top)->prev = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a=7;
    int *b=malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b=9;
    
    StackNode *stackHeadSameObjects=NULL;
    Push1(&stackHeadSameObjects, &a);
    Push1(&stackHeadSameObjects, b);

// with Push1 if a modify a or b, also will be modified in stackHeadSameObjects

    StackNode *stackHeadCopyOfObjects=NULL;
    Push2(&stackHeadCopyOfObjects, &a);
    Push2(&stackHeadCopyOfObjects, b);

// with Push2 if a modify a or b, these won't be modified in stackHeadCopyOfObjects
}
```

OR I also can redefine the structure like this:

```
typedef struct StackNode
{
    int data;
    struct StackNode *prev;
} StackNode;
```

So there is no need to allocate memory anymore and it is similar to what Push2 does (Copy the Object).

Comment: If all you have is a single "object" (like a single `int` value) then you don't need a pointer. *Except* if you're programming in C++ and the object is polymorphic. So please in the future don't use terms like "C/C++" as they really are two very different languages.

Comment: Hint: get rid id the `if(){` s. They are not needed.

Comment: You seem to be confusing objects and pointers -- a common problem among newcomers to C and low-level languages in general

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are *not* storing an object in your data structure, you're storing a pointer to an object in your data structure.  Now a pointer is itself an object, but that is distinct from the object it points at.  Because you are storing a pointer, you need to worry about the lifetime of the thing you are pointing at, lest the pointer become dangling.  It also means that any changes to the object you later make through the pointer will affect the original object.

With the copy of the object, you're making a copy, which has its own lifetime and existence independent of the original object.  Changes to the copy do not affect the original.

So the behavior of the two cases is completely different -- which one you want depends on what you are trying to do.